# Quais são as diferenças entre __autoload e spl_autoload_register?

Tags: php, php-autoload, spl

No php, temos dois métodos de efetuar um `autoload` de classes:

## função __autoload

Exemplo:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2();
```

## função spl_autoload_register

Exemplo:

```
class Autoloader
{
   public static function load($class)
   {
         require $class . '.php';
   }
}

spl_autoload_register(['Autoloader', 'load']);

// ou
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
     return $class . '.php';
});
```

É claro que, a princípio, vemos que as diferenças está na declaração: Um, você tem que declarar uma função chamada __autoload, e outro, você usa uma função (já existente) chamada `spl_autoload_register`.

Porém, o Manual do PHP não recomenda o uso de `__autoload`, porque em versões futuras poderia ser removida (na verdade, não sei se tem mais esse aviso no manual, porque eu não o encontrei lá quando li o manual de `__autoload` novamente).

Sendo assim:

- Quais são as diferenças entre as duas?
- Por que o uso de `spl_autoload_register` é (ou era) encorajado, ao invés de `__autoload` (já que, a princípio, `__autoload` parece mais fácil de usar)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função `__autoload()` funciona como métodos mágicos como o `__construct()`, `__destroy()`, `__string`, etc.

O __autoload() captura o nome de uma classe não declarada.
Com o nome da classe, basta montar o "path" para carregá-la.
Caso a classe possua uma declaração, o `__autoload()` é ignorado.

É possível também simplificar a montagem dos "paths" apenas registrando suas bases com a função `set_include_path()` ou `ini_set('include_path','.')`.

A informação sobre desuso é válida e está reportada no link:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

> Tip spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is
>   discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

O texto já menciona o motivo básico no desencorajamento ao uso de `__autoload()` e preferência pela nova função `spl_autoload_register()`. A função `spl_autoload_register()` provê mais flexibilidade e melhorias em relação ao `__autoload()`.

**Invocando funções definidas pelo usuário**

A função `spl_autoload_register()` permite definir classes customizadas para a chamada dos eventos.

```
class AiSeEu
{
   public static function TePego($class)
   {
         require $class . '.php';
   }
}

spl_autoload_register(['AiSeEu', 'TePego']);
```

Em suma, permite que sejam criados vários __autoloads().
Pode parecer inútil pois é praticamente o mesmo resultado do `__autoload()`, porém, isso torna-se útil quando se trabalha com programação orientada a objetos.

**Parâmetros como função anônima**

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
     return $class . '.php';
});
```

Assim como qualquer outra função do PHP, é possível passar os parâmetros como função anônima.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

**Include path**

Note que, `set_include_path()` ou `ini_set('include_path','.')` também são válidos para funções invocadas por `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: +1 pelas informações, -1 pelo Teló :)

Comment: AiSeEu::tePego($class); throw new NaoPegouNadaException('erro causado no michel teló')

Comment: Dá vontade de editar essa pergunta, por causa desse Michel Teló

Answer (score 4):

`__autoload` é geralmente considerado obsoleto. Ele só permite um único carregador automático . Geralmente, você só deve usar `__autoload` se você estiver usando uma versão do `PHP` sem suporte para `spl_autload_register`.

`spl_autoload_register` permite que vários autoloaders serem registrados que serão executado até que uma correspondência seja encontrada. Isto significa que se você estiver usando o código do framework ou outras bibliotecas de terceiros que implementam suas próprias autoloaders você não precisa se preocupar com possíveis conflitos causados pelo seu autoload.

Fonte original: [Soen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894538/php-spl-autoload-register-vs-autoload)

Comment: ótimo complemento. Esqueci de mencionar sobre prevenção de conflito