# O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?

Tags: php, spl-autoloader-register

Qual o papel da função `spl_autoloader_register`, e em quais possíveis cenários está função poderia ser incluída?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O `spl_autoloader_register` é uma função que faz parte da [**SPL**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) que significa Standard PHP Library, que em Português seria algo como *Biblioteca PHP padrão*

> *Talvez* uma melhor tradução adaptada seria:
>
> - Biblioteca PHP para padrões
> - Biblioteca PHP para situações comuns
> - Biblioteca PHP para problemas comuns

Ela foi desenvolvida para ajudar a resolver uma série problemas comuns e está disponível desde o PHP5.0

### Lista de interfaces e funções

- `class_implements` — Retorna as interfaces que são implementadas pela classe
- `class_parents` — Retorna as classes pai de determinada classe
- `class_uses` — Retorna os `traits` usados por uma determinada classe
- `iterator_apply` — Chama uma função todos elemento em um "iterador"
- `iterator_count` — Conta o número de elementos do "iterador"
- `iterator_to_array` — Copia o iterador em um array
- `spl_autoload_call` — Tenta todas as funções `__autoload()` registradas para carregar a classe solicitada
- `spl_autoload_extensions` — Registra e retorna as extensões de arquivo padrões para o spl_autoload
- `spl_autoload_functions` — Retorna todas as funções `__autoload()` registradas
- `spl_autoload_register` — Registra a função dada como implementação de `__autoload()`
- `spl_autoload_unregister` — Retira a função dada como implementação de `__autoload()`
- `spl_autoload` — Implementação padrão de `__autoload()`
- `spl_classes` — Retorna as classes da SPL disponíveis
- `spl_object_hash` — Retorna uma identificação hash do objeto dado

No caso especifico da `spl_autoload_register` ela costuma ser usada pra registrar os eventos chamados. Um bom exemplo de uso seria para carregar uma classe de outro arquivo somente quando necessário.

Por exemplo vamos imaginar que temos um arquivo chamado global.php:

```
<?php
function meuAutoload($pClassName) {
    $path = __DIR__ . '/libs/' . strtolower($pClassName) . '.php';
    if (is_file($path)) {
        include_once $path;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('meuAutoload');
```

Você pode usar no index.php algo como:

```
<?php
require 'global.php';

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->test();
```

Veja que eu não declarei a classe `Foo`, então a função `meuAutoload` tentará carregar o arquivo na pasta `/libs/foo.php`, se o arquivo não existir, então irá emitir um erro.

Para que o erro não ocorra basta adicionar na pasta libs o arquivo foo.php, com o conteúdo:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
       //Algo aqui
    }
}
```

### Vantagens:

- Você só chama bibliotecas que realmente vai usar
- Só é chamada se a classe **não** estiver definida
- Melhora a performance do script, já que só será adicionado o que vai usar mesmo
- Não precisa incluir "manualmente" com `require` ou `include` as classes/bibliotecas necessárias.

### PSR-0 e PSR-4

O `spl_autoloader_register` é usado pelo PSR-0 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/pt-br/ e pelo PSR-4 que são padrões de carregamento automático de bibliotecas.

> Note que o PSR-0 está em desuso e deve-se usar o PSR-4.

Irei falar apenas no PSR-4, devido ao PSR-0 estar em desuso, a principal diferença do PSR-4 pro exemplo que mostrei anteriormente é que ele trabalha com namespaces e uma estrutura de pastas para organizar a sua biblioteca, isto é muito usado por vários frameworks atuais, como por exemplo  o Laravel.

Veja um código de exemplo, crie um arquivo chamado global.php:

```
function myAutoLoader($class)
{
    // Prefixo no namespace do projeto especifico 
    $prefix = 'Foo\\Bar\\';

    // Diretorio aonde ficam as bibliotecas
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';

    // Verifica se a classe chamada usa o prefixo
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // Se não usar o prefixo Foo\bar então retorna false
        return;
    }

    // Pega o caminho relativo da classe, ou seja remove o Foo\bar\
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // Troca os separadores de namespace por separadores de diretorio
    // e adiciona o .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    // Verifica se o arquivo existe, se existir então inclui ele 
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
```

> Meu código tem alguns detalhes diferentes do original, mas são coisas pertinentes ao meu ver para evitar falhas, como por exemplo, troquei `file_exists` por `is_file` e também não usei uma função anonima para dar suporte para o php5.3, também troquei `require` por `include_once` pra evitar que o `require` emita algum erro a mais (como descrito aqui [Classe autoload PSR4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635))

Um detalhe muito importante, a função usada no PSR-4 não deve emitir erros, ou interferir na exceção, o propósito é apenas incluir a biblioteca, acaso o arquivo não exista o erro deve ser o padrão que é gerado pelo próprio php, algo como:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'Foo\Bar\olamundo' not found in /home/user/projeto/index.php on line 2

Para usar, faça isto:

```
<?php
require 'global.php';

/*
Isto irá incluir ./src/exemplo1.php
*/
use Foo\Bar\exemplo1 as ApelidoParaExemplo1;
$foo = new ApelidoParaExemplo1;

/*
Isto irá incluir ./src/exemplo2.php
*/
$foo = new Foo\Bar\exemplo2;
$foo->teste();

/*
Isto irá incluir ./src/exemplo3.php
*/
class Teste extends Foo\Bar\exemplo3 {
}

/*
Isto irá causar erro, porque não usou o namespace padrão
*/
$foo = new Hello\Bar\exemplo2;

/*
Isto irá incluir ./src/a/b/c/d/teste.php
*/
$foo = new Foo\Bar\a\b\c\d\teste;
```

Note que todos arquivos incluídos devem estar dentro dos `namespaces` chamados, leia sobre `namespaces` aqui http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php.

O arquivos usados no exemplo devem ser algo como:

Arquivo `./src/exemplo1.php`:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

class exemplo1
{
   //Algo aqui
}
```

Arquivo `./src/exemplo2.php`:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

class exemplo2
{
   //Algo aqui
}
```

Arquivo `./src/exemplo3.php`:

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

class exemplo3
{
   //Algo aqui
}
```

Arquivo `./src/a/b/c/d/teste.php`:

```
namespace Foo\Bar\a\b\c\d;

class teste
{
   //Algo aqui
}
```

> Note que se você usar algo como:
>
> ```
> use Foo\Bar\Baz;
> ```
>
> E não executar `new Baz` ou um método ou variável estática por exemplo `Baz::foo();` o autoload não vai incluir o arquivo pois não é necessário, o `use` é apenas pra criar o apelido ou atalho, pois usando `use` que ao invés de usar `Foo\Bar\Baz` você poderá usar apenas `Baz`

**Perguntas relacionadas:**

- [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635)
- [Quais são as diferenças entre __autoload e spl_autoload_register?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75105/3635)
- [O que significa PSR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32295/3635)
- [Classe autoload PSR4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635)

Comment: uau, acho que não poderia ter esperado melhor, muito bom..