# Classe autoload PSR4

Tags: composer, php-autoload, dependências, php

Gostaria de criar um classe de **autoload** que siga as recomendações da **PSR4** e que possa utilizar em conjunto e de forma independente da autoload do **Composer**.

A aplicação que estou criando terá a seguinte estrutura:

```
/root
 |--/src                
      |-- /App
            |-- /Config
            |-- /Controller
            |-- /Model
      |-- /Core
            |-- /Helper
            |-- /lib
                  |-- Autoload.class.php
  |-- /public_html
        |-- ...
  |-- /vendor  
        |-- ...
  |-- index.php
```

Futuramente integrarei novos componentes na minha aplicação através do Composer mas, gostaria de uma classe autoload para as classes da minha aplicação.

Comment: tem o exemplo no site php-fig.org

Comment: Pelo que vi no exemplo de implementação da PSR-4 [neste link](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md),  para cada novo **namespace** que eu criar eu deverei adicioná-lo juntamente com o caminho do arquivo como neste exemplo:     `$loader->addNamespace('Foo\Bar', '/path/to/packages/foo-bar/src');`. Queria, no entanto, deixar isso automático.

Comment: o exemplo eh meramente didatico... implementações como a automação que deseja fazer, é por conta do developer

Comment: mas se vc sair da proposta do psr-4 já não estará mais como psr-4, entende?  O padrão serve justamente para evitar aquelas gambiarras monstruosas em autoloaders... eu mesmo já criei muito desses monstros... hoje procuro seguir o psr-4..  pode parecer ilogico ter varios arquivos autoloaders, mas eh melhor.. No final das contas nem terá muito... normalmente utilizo apenas 2, sendo 1 para funções do core e outro para o aplicativo onde contem os modelos de negocios

Comment: Sim. Quanto a utilização de 2 ou mais autoloads não vejo problema. Mas ter que registrar as namespaces achei um pouco confuso. Aparentemente não há nenhuma restrição que obrigue esse *registro*. Isso seria um passo atrás na minha opinião.

Comment: eu tb não uso a tecnica do “registro” presente no exemplo do site.. alias foi a primeira coisa que removi  rsrsr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo a estrutura que você usou, bastaria criar um evento em um arquivo .php que será incluído dentro do index.php (que deve ir dentro de `public_html`), note que o `public_html` será o seu root (pro servidor), no entanto isto não é um obrigação, só estou seguindo a sua estrutura de pasta.

Pra isto você terá que usar o `spl_autoload_register`, o link http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/ - eu fiz um exemplo, com algumas modificações:

```
<?php
function myAutoLoader($class)
{
    // Diretório aonde ficam as bibliotecas
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/App/'; //A pasta que conterá os arquivos que serão autocarregados

    //Transforma namespace no caminho do arquivo
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';

    // Verifica se o arquivo existe, se existir então inclui ele
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
```

Você pode colocar isto dentro (ou usar `include`) dentro do teu `index.php`, ou criar um arquivo dentro de `Core` e usar `include` chamando ele.

Pra mais detalhes, veja esta resposta que fiz: [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635)

### Notas sobre o código

- **Nota:** Diferente do http://www.php-fig.org eu usei `include_once` ao invés de `require`, pois se o arquivo já tiver sido incluído manualmente o ele não for uma classe, irá apresentar mais erros do que deve e o único erro que o padrão PSR-4 deve apresentar é o de *classe não definida*.
- **Nota 2:** Usei `is_file` ao invés de `file_existes`, pois apesar de ser quase impossível ainda sim um desenvolvedor que usar o teu projeto pode acabar criando uma pasta chamada `./src/App/Controller/foo.php/index.html`, claro que isto é um erro do usuário, mas como eu disse na outra **nota**, o PSR-4 só deve apresentar erros de *classe não definida* (que é o padrão) no entanto se o `require` tentar chamar uma pasta irá apresentar um erro como pois `file_exists` retorna `true` pra diretórios:

  > **Warning:** require(src/App/Controller/foo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **Z:\www\projeto\server.php on line 22**
  >
  > **Fatal error:** require(): Failed opening required 'src/App/Controller/foo.php' (include_path='.') in **Z:\www\projeto\server.php on line 22**

O motivo disto é porque esta descrito aqui http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification:

> As implementações de autoloader NÃO DEVEM lançar exceções, não devem gerar erros de qualquer nível e não devem retornar qualquer valor.

Comment: Olá, Guilherme! Você pode acrescentar um exemplo de como fazer Unit Tests no seu código acima? Obrigado.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway o PHPUnit usa `_` como separador de namespaces, o código acima se baseia no PSR-4, o qual exige \ como separadores (que é suportado a partir do php5.3). De qualquer forma você pode usar o composer-autoload que suporta ambos formatos, acredito que na proxima build do phpunit eles passem a usar \ ;D

Comment: Eu vou usar seu código com uma estrutura de diretórios diferente, mas já deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway lembrei que eu tinha feito um exemplo para funcionar com PSR0 (o qual aceita \ e _ como namespaces): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157958/3635

Comment: Tá faltando coisa nesse código aí, não? Onde é definida `$np`?

Comment: Obrigado @MestreLion esta corrigido