# Como evitar a repetição dos requires?

Tags: php

Tenho esse código que faz os includes:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "lib/conexao.php";
require_once "lib/functions.utilities.php";
require_once "lib/class.User.php";
$usr = new User(conectar());
timeValidation();
?>
```

Mas agora, eu preciso fazer uma parte de cliente e preciso ficar colocando o `../`?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../lib/conexao.php";
require_once "../lib/functions.utilities.php";
require_once "../lib/class.User.php";
$usr = new User(conectar());
timeValidation();
?>
```

Teria como eu falar para ele olhar direto o include sem ficar colocando `../`?

Comment: Já pensou em um autoloader ?

Comment: Quando você tiver um tempo, pesquise sobre [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). O Composer fazer todo esse trabalho de incluir os arquivos que você precisa.

Answer (score 5):

Se estiver errado me desculpe, mas suponho que um [`autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php) irá fazer o que você pretende elaborar, um exemplo simples seria este abaixo:

```
<?php

//jeito moderno
spl_autoload_register(function ($class){
    if(file_exists($class. '.class.php')){
        require_once($class. '.class.php');
    }
});


$obj = new autoload2();
$obj->setCor('azul');

echo "A cor da bola é: ".$obj->getCor();

echo "<br>";

?>
```

**autoload2.class.php**:

```
<?php

class autoload2{

    private $cor;

    public function setCor($c){
        $this->cor = $c;
    }

    public function getCor(){
        return $this->cor;
    }
}

?>
```

Esse é um exemplo que possuo aqui no meu computador.

Answer (score 2):

Não creio que seja necessário `spl_autoloader` para algo tão corriqueiro, muito menos PSR, afinal não esta tentando carregar classes baseadas em **namespaces**, na verdade creio que um dos includes nem seja uma classe.

Então eu diria que basta criar um arquivo chamado `global.php` e nele adicionar tudo o que precisa, desta forma iria precisar usar o `require_once` apenas uma vez para cada documento, por exemplo:

**global.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "lib/conexao.php";
require_once "lib/functions.utilities.php";
require_once "lib/class.User.php";
$usr = new User(conectar());
timeValidation();
```

Então em ambas partes adicionaria somente isto:

```
<?php
require_once 'global.php';
```

E:

```
<?php
require_once '../global.php';
```

Se for usar `spl_autoloader` recomendo padronizar seguindo os namespaces e o PSR-4, como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635

Você pode usar o `composer` também, mas não é necessário, a vantagem do `composer` esta mais em poder usar bibliotecas de terceiros facilmente em seus projetos.

Comment: Interessante e bem simples a sua solução para algo tão *trivial*. Aproveitando, há um ganho/perda (que não seja irrisório) usando dessa maneira ao invés de usar tudo manualmente? Tirando a necessidade de repetir.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis nem sei se usei a palavra *trivial* no momento correto, ou se ela foi apropriada, talvez escrever "algo simples" soaria melhor? :P

Comment: Talvez comum/simples/corriqueiro seja a sua palavra. Apesar que, acho que foi bem usada *trivial*.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis "corriqueiro" :)

Answer (score 1):

Não é a melhor maneira de fazer, acho que é até uma má prática fazer isso que vou sugerir, mas você pode criar um arquivo chamado por exemplo "includes.php". Nesse arquivo você dá o `require_once()` de todos os arquivo que você precisa. Depois de feito isso, você vai na parte do cliente e só da um `require_once()` do "includes.php".

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Você pode criar um arquivo `composer.json` assim na raíz do projeto:

```
{
    "require": {},

    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            ""  : "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Onde `""` seria o namespace. Porém como não é usado, deixei em branco. 
`"src"` seria a pasta raiz das classes.

Exemplo:

```
src/
   MinhaClasse.php
```

O conteúdo da classe `MinhaClasse.php`, tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
class MinhaClasse
{

    public static function metodo()
    {
        echo 'método chamado', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Em seguida, rode o seguinte comando:

```
 composer dump
```

ou

```bash
php composer.phar dump
```

Uma pasta `vendor` será gerada. Em seguida, basta apondar um único include para o arquivo `vendor/autoload.php`, que tudo funcionará. Veja:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


MinhaClasse::metodo();
```

<sub>O processo não é difícil, eu fiz exatamente esse teste com menos de 10 minutos e configurei esse exemplo</sub>

**Nota**: Você pode usar o comando `composer init` para gerar o arquivo composer.json de maneira mais  rápida e fácil.