# autoload nas classes - php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

É um esquema que estou inventando já que neste projeto não vou por framework por ser muito simples,

Trabalho com MVC no Framework (Codeigniter),

Mas eu não tenho classe Model separada com carregamento (só como arquivo), é sempre uma extenção da Controller, então vou criar a minha controller, dar um nome para elas no config de inicialização e quero que o load carregue todas estas que estão no vetor, junto com o model de cada uma.

O que está faltando, é ele dar automaticamente o load com o nome da $variavel sendo o nome da Controller em letra minuscula, e o new = Classe; no lugar da palavra "Classe" quero o nome do arquivo que é o mesmo nome da classe da Controller.

Resumindo, carregar automático, mas já dar o comando new de inicializar a classe, ele está dando erro.

Código:

```
<?php
/* ------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Configuração do php
 * ------------------------------------------------------ */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/* ------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Configuração inicial do Sistema
 * ------------------------------------------------------ */
$base_url           = 'http://localhost:8081/bitbucket/16.4.2/';
$index_page         = 'index.php';
$charset            = 'ISO-8859-1';
$autoload           = 1;
/* ------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Configuração do autoload
 * ------------------------------------------------------ */
$autoload['Controller']     = array(
  "Cliente",
  "Administrador",
  "Ticket",
  "Notificacao"
);
$autoload['lib']            = array("buscaCep","fup");
/* ------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Carrega a configuração
 * ------------------------------------------------------ */
  spl_autoload_register(function ($nome) {
    global $base_url;
    foreach($autoload['Controler'] as $elemento):
      if ($elemento == $nome):
        $Controller = $base_url."Controller/".$nome.".Controller.php";
        if(is_file($Controller)):
          $Model = $base_url."Model/".$nome.".Model.php";
          if(is_file($Model)):
            include_once("$Model");
          endif;
          include_once("$Controller");
          ${strtolower($nome)} = new {$nome};
        endif;
      endif;
      $x++;
    endforeach;
  });
/* ------------------------------------------------------ *
 * Inicializar Controllers com o comando ''$nomedoobj = new Controller';
 * ------------------------------------------------------ */
//$administrador  = new Administrador();
//$ticket = new Ticket();

foreach($autoload['Controler'] as $elemento):
  ${strtolower($elemento)} = new {$elemento};
endforeach;
?>
```

**Linha com erro é:**

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/andre/public_html/bitbucket/16.4.7/conf.php on line 49

**Código:**

```
${strtolower($nome)} = new {$nome};
```

O nome do arquivo onde está a classe é **Controller/Administrador.Controller.php**

E aqui está o código:

```
<?php
class Administrador extends AdministradorModel {

    function helloworld(){
        echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
    }
}
```

Eu imagino que o código que digitei na **linha com erro** seria a teoria de como eu quero que funcione, claro, ele tá errado, mas **como poderia ser** ?

Comment: Boa noite André, eu não entendi o objetivo disto `${strtolower($nome)}`

Comment: fazer o php digitar pra mim o $nomedaclasse = new Nomedaclasse;

Comment: Sim mas a variavel estará dentro do escopo da função, ou seja ela não esta sendo usada pra nada, entendeu?

Comment: Mas eu posso levar esse comando pra fora da função num foreach dentro do conf.php, aí funcionaria a teoria, mas o código continuaria dando erro. certo?

Comment: Não quero ficar carregando as classes cada vez que for usar, nem quero digitar denovo em lugar nenhum, quero que já inicialize as classes configuradas no próprio vetor do conf, logo que iniciar o conf.php, tanto o arquivo quanto o new

Comment: Tá eu entendo o que você quer fazer em base, mas eu quero entender aonde (local exato) que vai usar o `${strtolower($nome)}`, pois existem varias maneiras de se fazer uma mesma coisa. Estou tentando ver uma solução alternativa, mas se você não explicar o objetivo dentro do código eu não posso dar uma resposta ;)

Comment: Quero usar no final do confi.php, ali onde tá comentado, olha a ultima linha

Comment: Seria o `$ticket = new Ticket();`?

Comment: isso, o Ticket tá ecrito lá no vetor chamado $autoload['Controller'], lá em cima, quero um foreach pra executar o comando mágico que seria exatamente esse que tu falou aí, só que para cada uma do vetor, por isso tem que ser mágico kk.

Comment: Olha vendo daqui parece que o seu código na lógica dispara duas vezes o `new ...` pra uma chamada, um na hora que chama `$ticket = new Ticket();` e outro dentro do SPL, acho que talvez você não tenha entendido o SPL_AUTOLOAD, veja se esses links ajudam: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635

Comment: É que fiz correndo vai disparar duas vezes sim tem que tirar ele lá da load e por no rodapé do conf.php, e também tirar o autoload da função initialize..., tá errado mesmo eu vi agora pouco, mas eu queria um jeito de carregar as classes do vetor sem ter que digitar, é o comando que falta.

PS. VOU EDITAR E CORRIGIR O QUE JÁ VI ERRADO,
PS2. PRONTO

Comment: André acho que se tiver um pouco mais de paciencia e tentar entender o spl_autoload e ler o link que passei vai conseguir implementar melhor ;)

Comment: logo no início tem um erro, $base_url compõe o path que deveria ser físico, mas é uma url, é virtual...   is_file e include deveriam receber um path do filesystem  (c:\www\folder\file.php)...  primeiro deve começar a corrigir isso.