# Fazer require_once dentro das classes. É possível?

Tags: php, mvc, php-7

Estou tentando criar uma **arquitetura** nova baseada em uma *necessidade* minha e estou tendo alguma **dificuldade**.

Então resolvi criar um exemplo **mínimo, completo e verificável** da aplicação.

Trata-se de uma **arquitetura** **MVC** que estou tentando modificar a fim de atender a uma necessidade pessoal.

Bom, segue a **árvore**

```
conexao 
        Conexao.php
controle
        CPessoas.php
modelo
        MPessoas.php
visao
        VPessoas.php
erros.php
index.php
```

Segue os **arquivos**:

**Conexao.php:**

```
<?php

 class Conexao {


    private $host     = "localhost";    
    private $db       = "banco";     
    private $user     = "ususarioBanco";
    private $password = "senhaBanco";

    private $conexao;

    public function abreConexao() {

        if (isset($this->conexao))      {

            return $this->conexao;

        }  else {       

                $this->conexao = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);

                $this->conexao->set_charset("utf8");    

                return $this->conexao;
        }

    }

    public function fechaConexao () {

        if ($this->conexao != null) {

            $this->conexao = null;

        }
    }

  }

?>
```

**CPessoas.php:**

```
<?php

require_once "../conexao/Conexao.php";

class CPessoas {

    private $conexao;

    public function __construct() {
        $connection = new Conexao();
        $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();
        $this->conexao = $conexao;
    }

    public function cadastrar( $_pessoa ) {

        $string = "INSERT INTO (nome, idade) VALUES (" . $_pessoa->getNome() . "," . $_pessoa->getIdade() . " )";

        return $conexao->query( $string );

    }

}
```

**MPessoas.php:**

```
<?php

class MPessoas {

    private $id;
    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public function __construct( $_nome, $_idade ) {

        $this->nome = $_nome;
        $this->idade = $_idade;

    }

    public function setId( $_Id )$this->id = $_id;

    public function getId() return $this->id;

    public function getNome() return $this->nome;

    public function getIdade() return $this->idade;


}
```

**VPessoas.php:**

```
<?php

require_once "../modelo/MPessoas.php";
require_once "../controle/CPessoas.php";

class VPessoas {

    public function __construct() {}

    public function novaPessoa( $_nome, $_idade ) {

        $pessoa = new MPessoa( $_nome, $_idade );

    }

    public function cadastrar( $_pessoa ) {

        return $pessoaComtrole->cadastrar( $_pessoa ) ? "Cadastrado com sucesso" : "Erro no cadastro";

    }


}
```

**erros.php**

```
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
ini_set( "display_startup_erros", 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL && E_NOTICE );
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões 
error_reporting(
    E_ERROR |
    E_WARNING |
    E_PARSE |
    E_NOTICE |
    E_CORE_ERROR |
    E_CORE_WARNING |
    E_COMPILE_ERROR |
    E_COMPILE_WARNING |
    E_USER_ERROR |
    E_USER_WARNING |
    E_USER_NOTICE |
    E_ALL |
    E_STRICT
); // Todas as outras versões 
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );

require_once "erros.php";
require_once "visao/VPessoas.php";


$vpessoa = new VPessoas();

$pessoa = $vpessoa->novaPessoa( "Carlos", 49 );

$vpessoa->cadastrar( $pessoa );


?>
```

Mas, como era de se esperar, eu teria um **erro**:

```
Warning: require_once(../modelo/MPessoas.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc\visao\VPessoas.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../modelo/MPessoas.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc\visao\VPessoas.php on line 3

Logo de inicio por ter incluido as classes fora da página index usando require_once.
```

**A dúvida**: Será que dá para fazer tipo um `import` do `java` de forma a evitar a `importação` de todas as `classes` na **home page**?

Comment: Caro Carlos provavelmente o que deseja é isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88023/3635

Answer (score 2):

Uma coisa que você precisa ter claro é que `include` (ou `require`) é diferente de `import`.

Quando você faz o `include` de um arquivo no `index.php`, para o interpretador PHP é como se você copiasse todo o código deste arquivo e colasse dentro do próprio `index.php`. Ou seja, se você faz `require_once "../modelo/MPessoas.php"` o caminho será **relativo em relação ao `index.php`**, não ao próprio arquivo `VPessoas.php`, o que explica o arquivo não ter sido encontrado.

Se o seu `index.php` é o *entry point* da sua aplicação, você 1) deverá sempre incluir os arquivos indicando o caminho relativo ao próprio `index.php`; 2) ou incluir os arquivos indicando o caminho relativo indicando o diretório atual (`__DIR__`).

Aliás, esse é um problema bastante comum em PHP e já foi resolvido através das PSRs 0 e 4, definindo padrões de nomenclatura e organização de diretórios para os seus arquivos, o que possibilita você definir estruturas de auto carregamento das dependências, como o próprio Composer faz e como descrito pelo Guilherme em

- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88023/5878)

Answer (score 0):

O `código` **final** sem uso de **autoloader** ficou assim:
**Conexao.php**

```
<?php

class Conexao {


    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db = "banco";
    private $user = "usuarioBanco";
    private $password = "senhaBanco";

    private $conexao;

    public
    function abreConexao() {

        if ( isset( $this->conexao ) ) {

            return $this->conexao;

        } else {

            $this->conexao = new mysqli( $this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db );

            $this->conexao->set_charset( "utf8" );

            return $this->conexao;
        }

    }

    public
    function fechaConexao() {

        if ( $this->conexao != null ) {

            $this->conexao = null;

        }
    }

}

?>
```

**CPessoas.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . "/../conexao/Conexao.php";

class CPessoas {

    private $conexao;

    public
    function __construct() {

        $connection = new Conexao();
        $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();
        $this->conexao = $conexao;

    }

    public
    function cadastrar( $_pessoa ) {

        $string = "INSERT INTO pessoas (nome, idade) VALUES ('" . $_pessoa->getNome() . "'," . $_pessoa->getIdade() . ")";

        return $this->conexao->query( $string );

    }

}
```

**MPessoas.php**

```
<?
**VPessoas.php**

    <?php

    require_once __DIR__ . "/../modelo/MPessoas.php";
    require_once __DIR__ . "/../controle/CPessoas.php";

    class VPessoas {

        public
        function __construct() {}

        public
        function novaPessoa( $_nome, $_idade ) {

            return new MPessoas( $_nome, $_idade );

        }

        public
        function cadastrar( $_pessoa ) {

            $pessoaControle = new CPessoas();

            return $pessoaControle->cadastrar( $_pessoa ) ? "Cadastrado com sucesso" : "Erro no cadastro";

        }


    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );

require_once __DIR__ . "/erros.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/visao/VPessoas.php";

$vPessoa = new VPessoas();

$pessoa = $vPessoa->novaPessoa( "Carlos", 49 );

echo $vPessoa->cadastrar( $pessoa );


?>
```

**erros.php**

```
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
ini_set( "display_startup_erros", 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL && E_NOTICE );
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões 
error_reporting(
    E_ERROR |
    E_WARNING |
    E_PARSE |
    E_NOTICE |
    E_CORE_ERROR |
    E_CORE_WARNING |
    E_COMPILE_ERROR |
    E_COMPILE_WARNING |
    E_USER_ERROR |
    E_USER_WARNING |
    E_USER_NOTICE |
    E_ALL |
    E_STRICT
); // Todas as outras versões 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra resolução que consegui ma agora usando **spl_autoload_register**

**conexao.php**

```
class Conexao {


    private $host     = "localhost";    
    private $db       = "banco";     
    private $user     = "ususarioBanco";
    private $password = "senhaBanco";

    private $conexao;

    public function abreConexao() {

        if (isset($this->conexao))      {

            return $this->conexao;

        }  else {       

                $this->conexao = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);

                $this->conexao->set_charset("utf8");    

                return $this->conexao;
        }

    }

    public function fechaConexao () {

        if ($this->conexao != null) {

            $this->conexao = null;

        }
    }

  }
```

**CPessoas.php**

```
class CPessoas {

    private $conexao;

    public
    function __construct($_conexao) {

        $this->conexao = $_conexao;

    }

    public
    function cadastrar( $_pessoa ) {

        $string = "INSERT INTO pessoas (nome, idade) VALUES ('" . $_pessoa->getNome() . "'," . $_pessoa->getIdade() . ")";

        return $this->conexao->query( $string );

    }

}
```

**MPessoas.php**

```
class MPessoas {

    private $id;
    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public
    function __construct( $_nome, $_idade ) {

        $this->nome = $_nome;
        $this->idade = $_idade;

    }

    public
    function setId( $_id ) {
        $this->id = $_id;
    }

    public
    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public
    function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public
    function getIdade() {
        return $this->idade;
    }


}
```

**VPessoas.php**

```
class VPessoas {

    public
    function __construct() {}

    public
    function novaPessoa( $_nome, $_idade ) {

        return new MPessoas( $_nome, $_idade );

    }

    public
    function cadastrar( $_pessoa, $_pessoaControle ) {

        return $_pessoaControle->cadastrar( $_pessoa ) ? "Pessoa cadastrada com sucesso" : "Erro no cadastro da pessoa";

    }


}
```

**erros.php**

```
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
ini_set( "display_startup_erros", 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL && E_NOTICE );
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões 
error_reporting(
    E_ERROR |
    E_WARNING |
    E_PARSE |
    E_NOTICE |
    E_CORE_ERROR |
    E_CORE_WARNING |
    E_COMPILE_ERROR |
    E_COMPILE_WARNING |
    E_USER_ERROR |
    E_USER_WARNING |
    E_USER_NOTICE |
    E_ALL |
    E_STRICT
); // Todas as outras versões
```

**index.php**

```
require_once "erros.php";

function loader( $class ) {

    $paths[] = "conexao/" . $class . ".php";
    $paths[] = "controle/" . $class . ".php";
    $paths[] = "modelo/" . $class . ".php";
    $paths[] = "visao/" . $class . ".php";

    foreach ( $paths as $path ):

        if ( file_exists( $path ) ) require_once $path;

    endforeach;

}

spl_autoload_register( 'loader' );

$conexao = new Conexao();

$connection = new Conexao();
$conexao = $connection->abreConexao();

$cPessoa = new CPessoas( $conexao );

$vPessoa = new VPessoas();
$pessoa = $vPessoa->novaPessoa( "Carlos", 49 );

echo $vPessoa->cadastrar( $pessoa, $cPessoa );
```

Nessa versão, o **index.php** ficou maior