# Configurar Namespace e autoload PSR-0

Tags: php, namespace, php-autoload, psr

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com a seguinte estrutura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é fazer o autoload carregar as classes.

O arquivo **autoload.php**:

```
 function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    require $fileName;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

**Classe abstrata Pessoa**

```
namespace Projeto\Cliente;

use  Projeto\Cliente\Interfaces\ClienteEnderecoInterface;
use  Projeto\Cliente\Interfaces\ClienteImportanciaInterface;

abstract  class Pessoa implements ClienteEnderecoInterface, ClienteImportanciaInterface{}
```

**Interface ClienteEnderecoInterface**

```
namespace Projeto\Cliente\Interfaces;
interface ClienteEnderecoInterface {}
```

**interface ClienteImportanciaInterface**

```
namespace Projeto\Cliente\Interfaces;
interface ClienteImportanciaInterface {}
```

**Classe ClientePF**

```
namespace Projeto\Cliente\Tipos;
use Projeto\Cliente\Pessoa;
class ClientePF extends Pessoa{}
```

**Classe ClientePJ**

```
namespace Projeto\Cliente\Tipos;
use Projeto\Cliente\Pessoa;
class ClientePJ extends  Pessoa {}
```

**Index.php**

```
require_once('./inc/autoload.php');
  $cli = new ClientePF();
  $cli2 = new ClientePJ()
```

Ao tentar carregar o index, o php o sistema informa que não consegue localizar as classes:

> ```
> ( ! ) Warning: require(ClientePF.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\inc\autoload.php on line 15 Call
> Stack
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  152944  {main}( ) ...\index.php:0 2 0.0030  157944  spl_autoload_call (
> ) ...\index.php:33 3  0.0030  158000  autoload( ) ...\index.php:33
> ```

Qual deve ser a maneira correta de declarar os namespaces e o autoload? 
Código Completo pode ser baixado aqui: [GitHub](https://github.com/musicao/projetopoo)
Dada a exitência da psr-4, posso usá-la em substituição da psr-0

Comment: Eu acho que facilitaria sua vida usar o Composer, mesmo que não instale dependências, ele geraria o autoload para você automaticamente.

Comment: E essa pasta Arquivos de Código-Fonte, a pasta Inc tá dentro dela ?

Comment: A idéia é fazer sem composer. Pra aprender a usar os namespaces

Comment: Tudo está dentro dessa pasta  Arquivos de Código-Fonte. Já é uma estrutura do Netbeans.

Comment: Só para aprender, tudo bem. Mas eu te encorajo a fazer através da `PSR-4`, pelo fato da depreciação da Zero.

Comment: Se fosse usar em PSR-4 como ficaria?

Comment: Pelo que olhei no código você está usando o padrão mais proximo ao PSR-4, você quer usar classes namespace e com underscore (para versões feitas para PHP 5.0 até 5.2)?

Comment: Posso fazer em psr-4 então. o PHP que estou usando é o 5.4. Não preciso de underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PSR-0 diferente do PSR-4 suporta tanto `_` quanto `\` para se referir aos namespaces, claro que o `_` é uma simulação de namespace que era usado até o php5.2.

O PSR-0 esta em desuso como recomendação, todavia ainda existem libs mais antigas mantidas que usam o underscore, para fazer o autoload simples que segue o PSR-4 bastaria algo como expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635, veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
function myAutoLoader($class)
{
    // Diretório aonde ficam as bibliotecas
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/../src/'; //A sua pasta `/src`

    //Transforma namespace no caminho do arquivo
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $np) . '.php';

    // Verifica se o arquivo existe, se existir então inclui ele
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
```

Mas é possivel adaptar para que aceite classes com underscore (underline `_`), assim:

```
<?php
function myAutoLoader($class)
{
    $separador = '_';

    //Verifica se usa \\ como separador
    if (strpos($classname, '\\') !== false) {
        //Corrige problema no PHP5.3
        $classname = ltrim($classname, '\\');

        $separador = '\\';
    }

    // Diretório aonde ficam as bibliotecas
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/../src/'; //A sua pasta `/src`

    //Transforma namespace (sendo com \ ou _) no caminho do arquivo
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace($separador, '/', $np) . '.php';

    // Verifica se o arquivo existe, se existir então inclui ele
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
```

No caso eu usei `__DIR__ . '/../src/'` para subir um nível da pasta `inc`, pois acredito que você vai usar no index

### Sobre o seu código:

1. Em PHP para os includes eu não acho que seja necessário `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, em todas distros e sistemas operacionais que rodei aceitam perfeitamente `/`
2. Não usei `require`, porque o problema que deve ser emitido é o de `exception` de classe não encontrada, não testei `require`, mas ele causa finalização do script se não achar o arquivo, o que dará um erro esperado conforme as recomendações do PSR-4

Documentação:

- PSR-0: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- PSR-4: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

### Alguns links que perguntas e respostas sobre o assunto:

- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635)
- [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635)
- [Quais são as diferenças entre __autoload e spl_autoload_register?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75105/3635)
- [O que significa PSR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32295/3635)
- [Classe autoload PSR4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635)

Comment: O psr-0 não foi depreciado, como substituto ficou o psr-4?

Comment: Sim @rray esta explicado na resposta que linkei, por isso expliquei que deve ser usado se necessitar carregar uma lib mais antiga e mantida, o proprio composer-autoload faz o mesmo ainda. São recomendação e não normas ;) ... obrigado, aprovetei e linkei algumas coisas, se tiver algo para indicar só me avisar que adiciono a resposta.

Comment: @rray Acho que a palavra mais apropriada (se é que isso existe) para o termo em inglês *deprecated* é "obsoleto"

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway está correto.