# Como funciona [modus operandi] o autoload em PHP?

Tags: php, diretório, php-autoload

Suponhamos que eu tenha a seguinte estrutura de arquivos na raiz do meu site:

```
index.php
autoload.php

----| /Models
--------| /MainModel
------------| MainModel.php

----| /Controllers
--------| /MainController
------------| MainController.php
```

Suponhamos que exista um método em **MainModel.php** chamado de **mainMethod()** como segue:

```
<?php namespace Models\MainModel;

class MainModel
{

    public function mainMethod()
    {
        return json_encode(array('mensagem' => 'Tudo funcionando por aqui'));
    }
}
```

Na **index.php**, eu incluo o arquivo **autoload.php**

```html
<?php

include_once 'autoload.php';

// resto do código
```

O meu arquivo **autoload.php** tem o seguinte código:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    $prefix = '';

    $base_dir = __DIR__.'/';

    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        return;
    }

    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    $file = $base_dir.str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class).'.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

Agora, vem a bruxaria que eu não entendo como funciona. Se eu fizer:

```
<?php

include_once 'autoload.php';

$obj = new Models\MainModel\MainModel;


echo $obj->mainMethod();

// Output: {"mensagem": "Tudo funcionando por aqui"}
```

Mesmo se eu indicar as classes dos *controllers* o reconhecimento é o mesmo. Funciona!

Bem, eu tenho uma *closure* autoload que funciona, mas como essa *closure* funciona? Como o *autoloading* do PHP reconhece as classes dentro de pastas, mesmo eu tendo indicado somente a raiz do projeto?

O PHP está indo lá dentro das pastas e reconhecendo as classes, como isso é possível?

O grande detalhe disso tudo é que se o arquivo **MainModel.php** não estiver dentro de uma pasta **MainModel** (com o mesmo nome do arquivo) o *autoload* não funciona.

Outra coisa curiosa é que os *namespace* têm que indicar o caminho do arquivo até a classe a partir da raiz `Models\MainModel`, depois eu declaro a classe.

Eu não quero saber como usar o autoload, porque isso eu já consegui, mas sim como funciona, porque eu estou usando algo que eu não sei como funciona.

**Minha pergunta é completamente diferente da optada pelos moderados do site: ver ["possível duplicada"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163660/namespace-com-php)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `spl_autoload_register` intercepta todas suas chamadas que forem feitas assim:

- `$foo = new AlgumaCoisa();` instanciar uma classe
- `echo AlgumaCoisa::teste;` pegar uma constante
- `echo AlgumaCoisa::$teste;` pegar uma variável estática
- `$baz = AlgumaCoisa::funcao();` chama um método estático

Ele funciona como um "proxy", ele é executado antes de concluir a instancia da classe por exemplo.

Agora eu recomendo não usar require ou `require_once`, e nem `file_exists`, faça assim:

```
if (is_file($file)) {
    include_once $file;
}
```

Isso porque ele pode afetar os erros, pois se o erros esperado é `Class not found` quando a classe não existir o teu código vai emitir um erro de require, o que é certo, mas não para o PSR.

E o `file_exists` verifica arquivos e pastas, se por ventura tiver uma pasta com o nome `qualquercoisa.php` pode quebrar a aplicação, `is_file` não tem diferença de performance significativa se comparado `file_exists`, talvez só se executar 100.000 classes ao mesmo tempo você perca 0.0002 segundos.

Eu recomendo usar um destes exemplos:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635 (PSR-4)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157958/3635 (PSR-0)

Se for PSR-4 deve ficar assim, (adaptei para o seu caso e simplifiquei bem retirando o que acredito que não seria usado):

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $class = ltrim($class, '\\');

    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
});
```

de fator usar uma função anonima ou não é indiferente.

### Entendendo o código

Como disse você escreve o `spl_autoload` como desejar, existem várias maneira de implementar ele, mas vou explicar o código que escrevi:

- Remove `\` do começo (é um bug no php 5.3, nas demais versões esse problema não existe, então basicamente é uma "retrocompatibilidade"):

  ```
  $class = ltrim($class, '\\');
  ```
- Por exemplo, se `$class` recebe `Models\MainModel\MainModel`, isto irá trocar `\` por `/`:

  ```
  $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
  ```

  E gera isto na variavel `$file`:

  ```
  "Models/MainModel/MainModel.php"
  ```

Então a partir do valor de `$file` vamos checar se o arquivo existe e se existir ele irá incluir:

```
if (is_file($file)) {
    include_once $file;
}
```

E então o processo da chamada do `new Models\MainModel\MainModel` irá prosseguir

- **P:** O grande detalhe disso tudo é que se o arquivo MainModel.php não estiver dentro de uma pasta MainModel (com o mesmo nome do arquivo) o autoload não funciona.
- **R:** O autoload funciona, ele só não consegue fazer o include, pois não encontrou o arquivo
- **P:** Outra coisa curiosa é que os namespace têm que indicar o caminho do arquivo até a classe a partir da raiz Models\MainModel, depois eu declaro a classe.
- **R:** Isso é relativo, você implementa como quiser, mas em quase todas linguagens o namespace é representado por uma estrutura de pastas e arquivos, tem linguagens que não, como o C++, aonde o arquivo pode estar em qualquer lugar, pois o include dele não é feito no momento que usa a classe e sim quando usar `#include "localfisico.h"`

Comment: Eu já dei +1 pras duas respostas e as usei como referência. Mudei os detalhes das funções `is_file()` e `files_exists()` e estou usando *include*. Mas você poderia explicar mais como o autoload "puxa" as classes dos arquivos e por que é necessária uma estrutura de arquivos específica (ou não, porque no meu caso só funcionou com uma estrutura específica)?

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway editei a resposta e detalhei todos pontos da implementação, espero que ajude

Comment: Ótima pergunta e ótima resposta. Parabéns aos dois. :D

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado, @GuilhermeNascimento. **You saved my arse twice today**

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway adicionei duas explicações as suas duvidas especificas no final da resposta.